# Sockets: only one-way broadcast.?

Tags: sockets, udp, winsock, broadcast

I have broadcast server and client that written in C++. On one machine they runs and works great.

I try to use VBox with Win 8.1. I've installed Wireshark on it and on PC and run it on both sides.

First case. I've launched client on PC. Wireshark on PC shows that message send. Wireshark on Vm doesn't shows received message.

Second case. I've launch client on VM. Wireshark on PC shows received message.  And if i launch server on PC, all works great!

What it can be? Wireshark on vm in first case doesn't shows received broadcast message. Firewall disabled fully on both machines.

Comment: Also, VM has ip 10.0.2.15 and i can't ping it from PC. But, i think, broadcast message should reach all possible destinations. And also, Wireshark on PC on receive from VM shows IP of VBox DHCP - 192.168.56.1

Comment: That kind of information belonged in the question, not in a comment.  But if the PC can't ping the VM's IP, it can't broadcast to the VM's IP either. But there is a big difference between 10.0.2.15 and 192.168.56.1. What is the VM's actual IP? How is your VM network setup configured?